# Why no debug for Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am looking at the sample project for a [ColorPicker CustomControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms771620%28VS.85%29.aspx). I am trying to debug it to see how the code runs. I am getting

[image]

I think it has to do with

[image]

No build config for debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Configuration Manager (in the dropdown list in the toolbar) and add a Debug configuration to the project (not the solution).